# Creating private items

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Currently I have a light switch on some commerce items that make them private to users that are not logged in but they still show up when the user is logged out. Is there a way to do this? I'm continuing development for a webpage and I'm still new to craft so I am sort of lost

Answer (score 4):

Assuming `yourLightSwitchFieldHandle` is labeled "Hide From Logged Out Users", something like this should work.  Completely untested.

```
{# if the user is logged in OR they are not logged in but we don't want to hide the current product #}

{% if currentUser OR (not currentUser and not yourProduct.yourLightSwitchFieldHandle) %}
        Show Product
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Im not sure if it is labeled "Hide From Logged Out Users" how can I check?

Comment: It's just an example... the light switch can be either positive (Show to logged out users) or negative (Hide from logged out users) depending on how you've set things up. If it's negative, you need the `not` in front of `yourProduct.yourLightSwitchFieldHandle`. If it's positive, you don't.

Comment: Oh okay for sure I'll give it a try

Comment: Could I actually make a whole category private?